# How to assign columns as dates in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi guys in Ruby on Rails I have a table with 7 columns such as Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc which hold times...

I want these columns to be assigned to an actual day of the week so that if its tuesday the tuesday columns data(times) is rendered etc how do i go about doing this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
record.send(Time.now.strftime("%A").downcase)
```

This will call the day of the week ("sunday" through to "saturday") on whatever `record` represents.

Comment: so will this go into my model which is called bus_time sorry but I am a newbie

Comment: This will go wherever you need it, probably where you already have an instance of the bus_time model.